# C++ Class 'undeclared identifier"

Tags: c++, class

This is really frustrating, I've tried multiple variations of my class and constructor, sifted through pages of google results and other questions on this site but I can't figure it out. I believe the error is something simple that I'm overlooking.

Error code:

```
1>main.cpp(60): error C2065: 'Student' : undeclared identifier
1>main.cpp(60): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'newStudent'
1>main.cpp(60): error C3861: 'newStudent': identifier not found
```

student.h

```
#ifndef STUDENT_H
#define STUDENT_H
class Student {  
    private:
    static const int SIZE = 7;         // initial size of the array
    int *Students;                     // Students will point to the dynamically allocated array
    //int numStudents;                   // number of students currently in the list
    int rosterSize;                    // the current size of the roster
    int student_id;
    string name;
    string classification;
    public:
    Student();                         // constructor; initialize the list to be empty
    ~Student();
        void set_id(int);
        void set_name(string);
        void set_class(string);
            int print_id();
            string print_name();
            string print_class();
    //void enrollStudent();              
    //void Print(ostream &output) const; // print the list to output
};
#endif
```

student.cpp

```
        #include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include "student.h"

#define PROMPT "class> "
using namespace std;

Student::Student(){    // declared here right?
    student_id = 0;
    name = "";
    classification = "";
}

Student::~Student(){
    //delete Student
}

void Student::set_id( int i ){
    student_id = i;
}

void Student::set_name( string n ){
    name = n;
}

void Student::set_class( string c ){
    classification = c;
}

int Student::print_id(){
    return student_id;
}

string Student::print_name(){
    return name;
}

string Student::print_class(){
    return classification;
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "student.h"

#define PROMPT "class> "
using namespace std;


//**** Implement Error Handling ****\\

enum errorType {
    UNKNOWN_ERROR,
    INPUT_ERROR,
    HANDLER,
    NUM_ERRORS
};

// error messages

string errorMessage[NUM_ERRORS]= {
    "Unknown Error\n",
    "Input Error\n",
};

// error handler

void handleError(errorType err) {
    if(err > 0 && err < NUM_ERRORS)
        cout<< "Error: "<< errorMessage[err];
    else cout<< "Error: "<< errorMessage[UNKNOWN_ERROR];
}

//**** END Error Handling ****\\



void getInput() {


    int id; string n, c;
    cin>>id>>n>>c; 
    //cout<<id<<"-"<<n<<"-"<<c<<endl;
    Student newStudent();      //****WORK DAMN U!
    //set_id(id);
    //print_id();

    return;
}


int main() {
    //Student newStudent();   /* <-- why doesn't this work?!*/
    string input = "";
    bool finished = false;

    cout<<PROMPT; // prompt the user
    while(!finished) {
        if(input!="") cout<<PROMPT;
        cin>>input;
        if(input=="enroll") {
            cout<<PROMPT<<"Enroll student:"<<endl;
            getInput();
        }
        else if(input=="drop") {
            cout<<PROMPT<<"Enter ID:"<<endl;
        }
        else if(input=="roster") {
            cout<<"This will print formatted list of students"<<endl;
        }
        else if(input=="quit") {
            finished=true;
        }
        else handleError(errorType(1));
    }
}
```

Just as a note, my professor said adding 
 #include student.h
to my main.cpp
would fix my issue. OBVIOUSLY NOT because I included it in my student.cpp SO THANKS. ಠ_ಠ

tl;dr here is a smaller barebones version that gets same errors:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#define PROMPT "class> "

using namespace std;

class Student {
private:
int student_id;
string name;
string classification;
public:
Student();    // constructor
~Student();
void set_id(int);
int print_id();
};

Student::Student(){
    student_id = 0;
    name = "";
    classification = "";
}

Student::~Student(){
//delete Student
}

void Student::set_id( int i ){
    student_id = i;
}


int Student::print_id(){
    return student_id;
}


void messenger(){
int id;

   Student newStudent();

   cin>>id;      //this will drop the name and class
   newStudent.set_id(id);
   newStudent.print_id();
return;
}

void main() {
//Student newStudent();
string input="";
bool finished=false;

cout<<PROMPT; // prompt the user
        while(!finished) {
                if(input!="") cout<<PROMPT;
                cin>>input;
                if(input=="enroll") {
                        cout<<PROMPT<<"Enroll student:"<<endl;
                        messenger();
                        //cin>>input;
                        //newStudent.enroll(input );
                }
                else if(input=="drop") {
                        cout<<PROMPT<<"Enter ID:"<<endl;
                }
                else if(input=="roster") {
                        cout<<"This will print formatted list of students"<<endl;
                }
                else if(input=="quit") {
                        finished=true;
                }
        }
}
```

Comment: Did you try your professors solution? Did it work? What `#include` does it to literally include the specified file into the source, with the result being a file containing both the included files and the source. If it's included in one source file, then it's not automatically included in another. If `"student.h"` is not included in `main.cpp`, then how would the functions in `main.cpp` know anything about the stuff declared in `student.h`?

Comment: right, I understand the professor's statement now. at first I thought it was redundant to include it in both .cpp files, but this doesn't fix the issue. Are my constructor/class improperly defined?

edit: yes, tried professors solution

Comment: BTW, class is a reserved word in C++. Are you sure that #define PROMPT "class> " will not cause issues?

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried to initialize the Student object without the parentheses?

```
Student newStudent;
```

This calls the default constructor.
What you did with

```
Student newStudent();
```

is to declare a function which takes no parameters and returns a Student object.

Comment: Also known as [the most vexing parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse).

Comment: @conman: The only purpose of your post seems to be to get your homework done and make it work rather than understanding why it doesn't work or where you are going wrong.I am afraid that is not going to take you very far.

Comment: Compiled the code here and it works - without the parentheses. BTW: string is in namespace std and defined in header <string>

Comment: @conman, that is the error, and it fixes your bare-bones example, once you change main to return an int, `int main() { ... }`

Comment: okay THANK YOU SO MUCH GUYS =D I got test.cpp to compile and spit back out an integer. I also had to switch IDE, VS C++ wasn't playing well.

Answer (score 4):

> Just as a note, my professor said adding `#include student.h`
>   to my `main.cpp` would fix my issue. OBVIOUSLY NOT because I included it in my `student.cpp`

Your `main()` needs to know what is the the type `Student` to be able to create its object.
So your professor is correct.

Each source file is compiled separately, So when the compiler compiles `main.cpp` it needs to ***see*** the definition of the type `Student`.It can only do so if you include the header `student.` which defines the type in `main.cpp`. Note that including the header in `student.cpp` has no bearing on the fact that the definition needs to be seen in `main.cpp` because both of them are compiled as separate files.

Comment: The original post has `#include "student.h"` on line 3 of main.cpp.

Comment: even so, including it in main.cpp doesn't fix the problem, I added a small barebones version that gets the same errors

Comment: @Als I agree. You're right to point out that his professor was correct. +1 for good explanation.